# DICOM image processing, visualization and GUI- C++ and Python

Tags: python, c++, opencv, visualization, dicom

I have a problem statement- to develop an application for processing DICOM images for diagnostic applications **from scratch**. It includes:

1. Image processing- model based segmentation and registration (C++)
2. Visualization- 2D and 3D image visualization (C++)
3. Graphical User Interface (Python)

**Is it feasible to develop this using C++ (for large chunk of image data) and Python for the GUI?**

What are the pros and cons of using **openCV**?

Which libraries would be suitable for this?

Comment: I don't think OpenCV has anything for you here.

Comment: implementing a DICOM library from scratch is unrealistic

Comment: Thanks @malat  for pointing out that. I have decided to go for VTK, ITK and Qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say go with VTK, ITK and Qt. Python brings nothing to the table in terms of GUI compared against Qt. VTK/ITK can read DICOM for you and probably also do segmentation and registration as needed.

Comment: There are Qt bindings for Python (actually two of them PySide and PyQt). And they work nicely with VTK Python bindings. Just saying.

Comment: Can FLTK (mentioned in the ITK user guide) be used instead of Qt? FLTK seems to be more lightweight. While using Qt, I would have to distribute Qt to the users who doesn't have it.

Comment: You can use PyDicom to parse/access dicom files.